# datetime conversion issue in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

if i try to cast string date to datetime like 
`select cast('12/01/2010' as datetime)` then 
it works

but if i try to cast like 
`select cast('22/01/2010' as datetime)` then it is giving error.

again if i try to cast string date to datetime like 
`select cast('2010/12/01' as datetime)` then it works 
but if i try to cast like 
`select cast('2010/25/01' as datetime)` then it is giving error. my requirement is whatever way user input date that should be successfully converted to datetime. please tell me best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the sql server assumes, that date format id mm/dd/yyyy - US format,

you want to use French format, so use convert

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/01/2010', 103)
```

instead you'll get an error because there in no such a month number - 22

The best solution when passing datetime as string - to use short(without timezone) ISO format:

```
yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use fixed '20111231' format. You do not need to use cast, convert or similar command.